# Change SVG fill when scrolling based on background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am building a `React` website that has `section` panels slide up using `position: sticky` on scrolling but having issues with `fixed` elements and their `color` appropriately to the `section` `background-color`.

Here is a simple snippet of the problem.

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

*,
 ::after,
 ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 24px 28px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

svg {
  fill: black; // Change to white over dark backgrounds
}

.sticky {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="32px" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z"/></svg></div>
<main>
  <div class="sticky">Section Light</div>
  <div class="sticky dark">Section Dark</div>
</main>
```

I have seen other examples when the overlaid elements are positioned as `absolute`, however they do not work in this case due to the `sticky` position used by each `section` panel. Also, using `mix-blend-mode` is not possible due to some sections using a background image and that just looks terrible.

Secondly, the site is built in `Gatsby` and `React` and I have access to each sections background color.

How can I change the color of the `menu` svg when scrolling over different background colors? I only want white or black.

Comment: Do you want the bars to change color one by one as the dark or light section moves over them? Also I think you need a few lines of JavaScript, is that OK?

Comment: @AHaworth. Preferably I would like the color change to be one by one. I was thinking of using a clippath on the SVG. Secondly JS is okay.

Comment: Hi, I was part way typing an answer (use intersectionObserver being the recommendation) when I realised I didn't understand how things would be structured with more than 2 sections. Could you add a couple perhaps and show how they are styled - it looked odd when I did it and scrolled up, a sort of overlap. Thanks.

Comment: @AHaworth. Thank you. Yes, that is the intention. The sections overlap. I actually believe the best solution is to add the menu into each section, passing the background color and then using `chroma` to determine if color is dark. However, in this case, I will have the logo overlapping each and because the position is sticky, I cannot hide the overflow.

Comment: Hi, would reproducing the menu lead to accessibility problems? I don't think it's necessary though. My confusion over the strange overlapping was that the light sections had no background - I've altered it to make them have white which I think is the intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use intersectionObserver to tell us when a new section is near the top of the viewport and change the color of the menu icon accordingly. And conversely, when a section comes out of being near the top, change the menu depending on the dark status of its immediate previous sibling element (i.e. the one underneath).

This snippet demonstrates that:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
  //List from MDN:
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    //   entry.boundingClientRect
    //   entry.intersectionRatio
    //   entry.intersectionRect
    //   entry.isIntersecting
    //   entry.rootBounds
    //   entry.target
    //   entry.time
    //eventually make the gradient chosen depend on the % overlap and the color of the previous sibling element
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      svg.style.fill = (entry.target.classList.contains('dark')) ? 'url(#white)' : 'url(#black)';
    }
    else {
      svg.style.fill = (entry.target.previousElementSibling.classList.contains('dark')) ? 'url(#white)' : 'url(#black)';
    }
  });
};
let options = {
  threshold: [ 0.9, 0.94, 0.98 ] // need to work on these thresholds
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
const stickies = document.querySelectorAll('main div.sticky');
stickies.forEach( sticky => {
  observer.observe(sticky);
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

*,
 ::after,
 ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  rpadding: 24px 28px;
  padding: 2vh 28px;
  rpadding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 999;
}

svg {
  fill: black;
}

.sticky {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: white;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="32px" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="black" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"  gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#000"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="white" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"  gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#fff"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <path d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
<main>
  <div class="sticky">Section 1 Light</div>
  <div class="sticky dark">Section 2 Dark</div>
  <div class="sticky">Section 3 Light</div>
  <div class="sticky">Section 4 Light</div>
  <div class="sticky">Section 5 Light</div>
  <div class="sticky dark">Section 6 Dark</div>
</main>
```

To get the menu icon bars to change as the section goes up or down we can sense the ratio of overlap and set the svg fill color with the appropriate linear gradient - having linear gradients for third, two thirds and completely full. The above snippet sets up thresholds and has made a start on using linear gradients but it's not complete - more calculation has to be done on getting the %s correct. I hope to have time to get back to this at some point.

Note,  in order to do this observing on viewports with varying aspect ratios the top padding of the nav has been altered to a relative value.